# Integer array to string in c programming

Tags: c

Lets say i have an integer array with ascii values.

```
int stringAscii = {"072", "101", "108", "108", "111", "032", 
                   "087", "111", "114", "108", "100"};
```

and i want to convert the ascii values to characters and combine them to a string:

```
char *string = stringAsciiToString(stringAscii);

printf("Output -> '%s'", string);
```

// output -> 'Hello World'

How would you make such a function? This is what i got so far;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

long int p,q,n,t,flag,e[100],d[100],temp[100],j,m[100],en[100],i;
char msg[100];
int prime(long int);
void ce();
long int cd(long int);
void encrypt();
void decrypt();

int main()
{
    p = 53;
    q = 61;
    printf("\nENTER MESSAGE\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",msg);

    for(i=0;msg[i]!=NULL;i++)
      m[i]=msg[i];
    n=p*q;
    t=(p-1)*(q-1);
    ce();

    encrypt();
    decrypt();

    strcpy(msg, "");

    for(i=0;en[i]!=-1;i++) {
      strcpy(msg, concat(msg, en[i]));
    }

    printf("%s", msg);

    return 0;
}

char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);                              //+1 for the zero-terminator
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}

int prime(long int pr)
{
   int i;
   j=sqrt(pr);
   for(i=2;i<=j;i++)
   {
      if(pr%i==0)
         return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}

void ce()
{
   int k;
   k=0;
   for(i=2;i<t;i++)
        {
            if(t%i==0)
                continue;
                flag=prime(i);
            if(flag==1&&i!=p&&i!=q)
            {
                e[k]=i; flag=cd(e[k]);
                if(flag>0)
      {
         d[k]=flag;
         k++;
      }
      if(k==99)
         break;
      }
   }
}

long int cd(long int x)
{
   long int k=1;
   while(1)
   {
      k=k+t;
      if(k%x==0)
         return(k/x);
   }
}

void encrypt()
{
   long int pt,ct,key=e[0],k,len;
   i=0;
   len=strlen(msg);
   while(i!=len)
   {
      pt=m[i];
      pt=pt-96;
      k=1;
      for(j=0;j<key;j++)
      {
         k=k*pt;
         k=k%n;
      }
      temp[i]=k;
      ct=k+96;
      en[i]=ct;
      i++;
   }
   en[i]=-1;
   printf("\nTHE ENCRYPTED MESSAGE IS\n");
   for(i=0;en[i]!=-1;i++)
      printf("%c",en[i]);
}

void decrypt()
{
   long int pt,ct,key=d[0],k;
   i=0;
   while(en[i]!=-1)
   {
      ct=temp[i];
      k=1;
      for(j=0;j<key;j++)
      {
         k=k*ct;
         k=k%n;
      }
      pt=k+96;
      m[i]=pt;
      i++;
   }
   m[i]=-1;
   printf("\nTHE DECRYPTED MESSAGE IS\n");
   for(i=0;m[i]!=-1;i++)
      printf("%c",m[i]);
}
```

Comment: How would you? This isn't Coders For Free.com ...

Comment: See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Arrays for information C arrays. There is also a section on data types.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have and what you have tried. Then tell us how it does or doesn't work.

Comment: This is an integer array with pointers converted to integers. You really should first get the basics right. Mabe you then can do your homework yourself or at least follow the advice in [ask].

Comment: `int stringAscii`?, Shouldn't it be `char *stringAscii[] = {..........};`? Unless those values are indeed integers, and not strings with `" "`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` => UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `stringAscii` array is:

```
int stringAscii[] = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 
                     87, 111, 114, 108, 100};
```

And not:

```
int stringAscii = {"072", "101", "108", "108", "111", "032", 
                   "087", "111", "114", "108", "100"};
```

Which is incorrect for two reasons:

- you need to have `stringAscii[]` as your array name.
- You can't have string `" "` values as members of an integer array. That is type conflict in C.

You can dynamically allocate space for `char *string` using [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm), and add your ascii integer values to the dynamic array one at a time.

You can [`free`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) the requested space at the end.

Something like this will help you get started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *stringAsciiToString(int stringAscii[], const size_t size);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int stringAscii[] = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 
                     87, 111, 114, 108, 100};

    const size_t size = sizeof(stringAscii)/sizeof(*stringAscii);

    char *string = stringAsciiToString(stringAscii, size);

    printf("Output -> '%s'\n", string);

    free(string);

    return 0;
}

char 
*stringAsciiToString(int stringAscii[], const size_t size) {
    int i, slen = 0;

    char *string = malloc((size+1) * sizeof(*string));
    if (!string) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        string[slen++] = stringAscii[i];
    }
    string[slen] = '\0';

    return string;
}
```

Output here: [Demo](http://ideone.com/wdliVr)